# Using Template classes in cuda / c++ code

Tags: c++, class, templates, cuda

I'm new to coding in cuda, (and not massively experienced in c++) so i've been reading around to try and find a solution to this problem, but dont generally understand what people try and explain, and have yet to get it working.

Basically, I have a .cu file which contains two things:

```
template <class ModelType>
__global__ void Stepkernel(ModelType *particles)
```

and:

```
template <class ModelType>
void runTest(ModelType *particles)
```

I then have a header file, SamplerI.h which I didn't write, but i'm trying to include a call to the void function above, so, below all the #includes i have:

```
template <class ModelType>
void runTest(ModelType *particles);
```

and then later in the header theres a function where i've included a call to the above.

the header and associated files are compiled in a library libdnest, i compile the .cu file with nvcc -c step.cu, and then link with:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp step.o -ldnest
```

Now, if the template isnt present (ie i just have a void function with no mention of ModelType) all of this goes great, and it compiles and runs, but as soon as i try and include the template I get the following compile error:

```
../../include/SamplerImpl.h: In member function ‘bool       DNest3::Sampler<ModelType>::step() [with ModelType = Banana]’:
../../include/SamplerImpl.h:121:   instantiated from ‘void DNest3::Sampler<ModelType>::run() [with ModelType = Banana]’
main.cpp:37:   instantiated from here
../../include/SamplerImpl.h:159: error: no matching function for call to     ‘runTest(Banana*)’
```

and i have no idea what to do to try and fix it...

Does anyone have any ideas? If i havn't explained well enough let me know and i'll try and include more info, I dont really know whats important.

Cheers
Lindley

Comment: You say you are not very experienced in C++. If you are more comfortbale in C#, you could check out [CUDAfy.NET](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/), a C# toolkit for programming CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have template in the same source file that uses it for the compiler to instantiate it.

Note that C++11 introduces "extern" but those are not supported by all compilers.

Comment: especially when dealing with CUDA which does not support C++11 yet

Comment: So hang on, at the moment in my main.cpp I have the following call: 
 
    Sampler<Banana> sampler = setup<Banana>(argc, argv);

Sampler is the class that contains the call to the cuda code, but Banana is of the class ModelType for which the Template is made.

So, i instantiate a sampler using a ModelType, so where do I need to put a reference to the function in the cu file, I dont really understand..

Comment: Ok, i ended up copying all the stuff from the cu into the header, and just compiled the whole thing with nvcc, at the veyr least, it has compiled... just gotta see if it works now!